# Disprove the possibility of such a triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

[image]

The image is not that good, but, consider the following figure to be true without actually constructing it,how can one person find a $fault$ in it.
The blue colour represents perpendicular,
The orange represents 70 $degrees$ and the green represents 50 $degrees$. Remember, you should not construct it using a compass because it is not possible to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that there exists such a triangle. Then, since every inner angle of the triangle is $60^\circ$, it has to be an equilateral triangle. Then, we know that the inner point, which is the orthocenter, has to exist on the bisector of each angle , but it does not exist on either. This is a contradiction.

Comment: thats what i was looking for, a simple yet elegant proof @mathlove

Comment: @ArchitNanda: You are welcome!